# Use comma function in formattable (R)

Tags: r, shiny, formattable

I'm trying to have thousand separator in my shiny table output.
The following are my code:

```
UI <- dashboardPage(     
  dashboardBody(        
    fluidPage(          
      selectInput(inputId = "TableName",
                  label = "Select Data of Interest",
                  choices = list.files(path = "CSVData", pattern = "AMD_")),          
      uiOutput("Channel"),    
      formattableOutput("ResultTable")         
    )
  )
)

Server <- function(input, output){      
  output$Channel <- renderUI({        
    df <- read.csv(paste("Pathname/",input$TableName, sep = ""))        
    selectInput(inputId = "ChannelSelect",
                label = "Select Channel:",
                choices = unique(df) %>% select(Channel))),
                selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE)        
  })

  output$ResultTable <- renderFormattable({

    df <- read.csv(paste("CSVData/",input$TableName, sep = ""))
    ChanSelect <- input$ChannelSelect    
    A1 <- df %>% filter(if(ChanSelect != "All") (Channel == ChanSelect) else TRUE) %>%
      select(Channel, Amount)        
    formattable(A1, list(
      `Amount` = comma(`Amount`, digits = 0, format = "f", big.mark = ","
    ))        
  })      
}
```

My df's are varied but all of them are in the format:

```
data.frame("Channel" = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
           "Amount" = c(1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000 ))
```

The problem is with the formattable part that it didn't work. I don't know how to input the function `comma()` properly with `formattable`.

Comment: Please provide your data, current and expected output to get more options. This is currently an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/250659#250659).

Comment: My data has columns of big numbers, let's say column D. I wish all the numbers in this column to have thousand separator

Comment: You can edit your post to add details. Please follow these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It might make it easier to get help.

Comment: I read it. It might take me a while to edit my question. I thought putting my actual codes and data here is a bad thing to do. My bad.

Comment: Do you need `formattable` here or could you just use `format`?

Comment: I preferred using formattable as I also need to use their other features. I can find examples of doing stuff like setting colors and line. But setting number format is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this:

**1. Create a Custom Function**

```
mycomma <- function(digits = 0) {
      formatter("span", x ~ comma(x, digits = digits)
      )
    }
```

Use for a single named column:

```
formattable(df, list(`Account` = mycomma(digits=0))
  )
```

Use for several columns:

```
formattable(df, 
            list(area(col = c(3:6)) ~ mycomma(digits=0))
  )
```

**2. pass the formattable function each time**

```
formattable(df, list(`Account` = formatter("span", x ~ comma(x, digits = 0))
      )
```

NOTE: You could just as easily create a custom function that could be passed a different function, like percent or accounting. YMMV

```
mysimpleformat <- function(fun = "comma", digits = 0) {
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  formatter("span", x ~ fun(x, digits = digits)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to add the thousand markers to your `Amount` column, you can do it as follows:

```
df <- data.frame("Channel" = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 "Amount" = c(1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000 ))
df$Amount <- format(as.integer(df$Amount), big.mark=",")
```